# Sort the outer map by the value of the nested map

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

Sorting the **outer** map `Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>`  by the *list size* in the **nested** map retaining the outer and inner keys as before.

Comment: There can be multiple values in the inner map. Which one do you want to sort by?

Comment: @shmosel I just updated the question

Comment: Are the lists ever mutated after the map is constructed?

Comment: @Ryan No, it's just for the **viewer**

Comment: @Hearen it's still ambiguous. You have Map<string<Map<string, List<int>>> if you split the double string into a class, Pair(string,string) and made it into a multimap Map<Pair, List<int>> THAT would be possible to sort, as you now only have 1 key for 1 list length. As it stands, the outer map that contains the map, can not be sorted.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I should have a try on that. Sounds better solution ~, thank you ~ Ryan

Comment: Your `Map<String, List<Integer>>` contains multiple list -> multiple list size per outer key -> you must describe how you sort the outer map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may solve this by generalizing the process:

```
private static <K,V,R> Map<K,R>
                       replaceAndSortValues(Map<K,V> m, Function<V,R> f, Comparator<R> c) {
    return m.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), f.apply(e.getValue())))
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(c.reversed()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                                  (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
                                  LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

This method creates a new map with the same keys as the specified one, replacing all values using the specified function and sorting the entries according to the reversal of the specified comparator. It uses Java 9’s `Map.entry(…, …)` factory. If you have to support Java 8 or `null` keys or values, you may use `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(…, …)` instead.

This method can now be used to replace you inner map’s `List`s with `Integer`s representing their sizes and sort them in descending order and use the replacement operation as replacement function of the outer map:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>
              getCallWithStateSizeGroup(ThreadDumpDo threadDumpDo) {
    return replaceAndSortValues(getCallStackWithStateGroup(threadDumpDo),
        m -> replaceAndSortValues(m, List::size, Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()),
        Comparator.comparing(m -> m.values().iterator().next()));
}
```

This does basically the same as your posted solution. The outer map’s comparator uses the fact that the new inner maps are already sorted, so their first value is the maximum. But there must be no empty inner map.

This could easily get adapted to keep the `List<ThreadDo>` and just sort them by size:

```
public static Map<String, Map<String, List<ThreadDo>>>
              getCallWithStateSizeGroup(ThreadDumpDo threadDumpDo) {
    return replaceAndSortValues(getCallStackWithStateGroup(threadDumpDo),
        m -> replaceAndSortValues(m, Function.identity(),
                                  Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)),
        Comparator.comparingInt(m -> m.values().iterator().next().size()));
}
```

We only have to change the inner map’s replacement function to `Function.identity()` and provide a comparator using the list’s sizes. The outer map’s comparator still can use the fact that the inner maps are already sorted at this point, but also has to extract the `size()` of the list for comparison.