# Gson cannot de-json-lize what it json-lized?

Tags: java, gson

```
public static String toJsonString(Object obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(obj);
}
```

Using this method to *json-lize* the object and then use this to *de-json-lize*

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(this.getThreadDumpVoJson(), ThreadDumpVo.class);
```

Everything works fine until I just added a new field to this `ThreadDumpVo`

```
Map<StackStatePair, Integer> traceStatePairSortedSizeGroup;
```

then `Exception` thrown as follows:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1540 path $.traceStatePairSortedSizeGroup.
```

The `StackStatePair` is defined as follows:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StackStatePair {
    String callStack;
    String state;
}
```

Previously I was trying to use `import javafx.util.Pair;` but it prompts the same issue, what's going on here?

I cannot use **composite** key?

```
"traceStatePairSortedSizeGroup": {
"StackStatePair(callStack\u003dDeadLoopThread.lambda$createBusyThread$0(DeadLoopThread.java:7)|DeadLoopThread$$Lambda$1/2080166188.run(Unknown Source)|java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), state\u003dRUNNABLE)": 1,
"StackStatePair(callStack\u003djava.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)|java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)|java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)|java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153), state\u003dWAITING)": 1,
"StackStatePair(callStack\u003djava.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)|java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)|java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)|java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209), state\u003dWAITING)": 1
 }
```

Comment: Please share your Json body

Comment: @Reaz Just updated, it's the smallest I can provide here.

Comment: Use JSON Formatter which is widely available online, so that it does not hurt the readers to read your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Reaz I removed the **useless** and provided the smallest snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use such composite key if you are parsing the JSON using Gson. The key itself is not a JSON String, which makes it not parse-able using Gson. It can only be parsed as a String.

This is not an array inside the `traceStatePairSortedSizeGroup`. If it was an array, then we could have stored the strings into a `String` array and then we could have parsed the values from the array. That's why you have the `JsonSyntaxException`.

If there is any chance to get your JSON body modified, then I would like to suggest you change it to keep it simple.

Comment: If you could, would you please spare some time to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753245/sort-the-outer-map-by-the-value-of-the-nested-map)? There is a dilemma for me to selecting the solutions.

Comment: I checked the post. This is too much engineering for me. First of all, why do you have to sort the items found from your threads? The threads are itself not sequential in execution. I do not understand the purpose. However, if you are in need of sorting them, I would not recommend you to keep the stored values in a JSON schema. I would highly suggest you keep the information, breaking into smaller pieces in the SQLite database, in which you can manage to come up with complex queries if needed.

Comment: thank you, Reaz. I will try to find other way around. Thanks for the help ~